# Where can I find phase diagrams for mag-thor alloys?

Tags: phase-diagram

Where can I find phase diagrams for Mg Th alloys? Thanks!

Comment: An appeal for general information is going to get absolutely trashed by people here. You may want to ask a more specific question.

Comment: Shoot, I was worried about that. Unfortunately I don't have a specific question, I just need phase diagrams. Should I perhaps delete and put this in meta?

Comment: No no no, the meta isn't for that. Just make the question very specific: "Where can I find phase diagrams for blah blah blah". I'm not sure asking for references is allowed either though...

Comment: Okay, so I changed the title and body from 'Does anyone...' to 'Where can I find...' and also made a few other changes. Does it look 'okay' or should we make a few more edits? The tips are much appreciated!

Comment: I made one more change, decided to take out 'links and references'.

Comment: Again, asking for 'general information' is no bueno. Just ask for the phase diagrams.

Comment: This seems fine as is. For the record: asking for references is acceptable, but we'd _prefer_ that you ask a conceptual question about the reason you need the references. (Of course sometimes there is no deeper reason and you just want to know where to look up some information next time you need it, and that's okay.)

Comment: I would prefer a conceptual problem as well. A Professor offered to mentor an undergraduate 'research' (I use that term loosely) project to build a piece of equipment however in order to receive funds a research question must be asked. Since work is already being done in my lab with Th and the Professor's lab has extensive experience with magnesium based alloys he thought this would be a good 'mix'. Either way, thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

If your institution has access, the ASM Alloy Phase Diagram Database (at asminternational.org) is a great place to start. In addition, searching on the CALPHAD (on sciencedirect.com), Journal of Phase Equilibria (springer.com, no longer published), and Thermochimica Acta (also on sciencedirect.com) can yield more recent articles on given binary systems. 
For general overviews, there have been a number of binary alloy phase diagram collections, including the ASM Handbook (Volume 3), and several editions of Binary Alloy Phase Diagrams edited by T. B. Massalski.  A decent research library should have these in the reference section.
I usually start on the ASM web site, then move to searching technical databases for relevant articles.

For your particular case, the Mg-Th diagram is available at ASM ([Mg-Th](http://www1.asminternational.org/asmenterprise/apd/BrowseAPD.aspx?d=b&p=Mg-Th/%22link%22)), and is reproduced from Massalski's second edition. The assessed phases include Mg, Mg$_{23}$Th$_{6}$, Mg$_{2}$Th (room temperature and high temperature variations), and Th.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for and after speaking with our Campus librarian I now have full access. Thank you!